# How to view SAS stored processes from within Excel SAS add-in?

Tags: excel, sas

I can save a stored process to SAS Folders (of which there are many: "My Folder","Public","Shared Data", etc.) , but when I click on the Reports button on the SAS add-in tab of Excel, and browse to SAS Folders, non of the sub folders appear, and it appears to be empty. Is this something to do with administrative rights that I may be lacking? Thank you.

Comment: are you using the same user in both applications?

Comment: Yes, this is just on my personal work computer.

Comment: Have you set up a local SAS Metadata Server, then?

Comment: i'm asking about sas user, not operating system user. In Excel: SAS->Tools->Connections

Comment: You just answered my question...connection was never set up. Thank you!

Comment: @RobertSoszyński  can you add that as an answer please?  Seems like a good solution!

Answer (score 0):

Every SAS application use a SAS user to authenticate with SAS Metadata Server to get access to objects, which are stored there like reports, stored processes, projects etc.

After SAS Add-In for Microsoft Office installation you have to specify a user who will be used in a connection to SAS.

You can do it in Microsoft Excel (**SAS->Tools->Connections**).

SAS Add-In for Microsoft Office uses the same connection profiles as SAS Enterprise Guide. So if you create a profile in SAS EG, the same profile should be available in SAS Add-In for MS Office and vice versa. Both of application are using .NET framework.

Other applications like SAS Data Integration Studio, SAS Management Console were written in Java and use a different profile mechanism.